# Weird behaviour of dropout layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a CNN model with tensorflow that implement dropouts layers.
I pass the is_training argument in the network function so the dropout will be disabled on testing phase, and i realised that the errors were significantly higher when i disable it.
if I'm testing the model with the dropout function (which is not logic) I get an error of 0.01 in average, while when i'm testing it by specifying that is_training is False (but still training it with dropout) I get an error of 0.8.
I can't understand where is my error

Here is the model function:

```
def conv_net(x, arch, is_training=False):

    # MNIST data input is a 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28 pixels)
    # Reshape to match picture format [Height x Width x Channel]
    # Tensor input becomes 4-D: [Batch Size, Height, Width, Channel]
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    ### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ###

    # Convolution Layer with F1 filters, a kernel size of K1 and ReLU activations
    pad = 'same'

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, arch['conv1'][0], arch['conv1'][1], activation=tf.nn.relu)
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, arch['conv2'][0], arch['conv2'][1], activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, arch['pool1'][0], arch['pool1'][0])
    drop1 = tf.layers.dropout(pool1, arch['dropout1'], training=is_training)

    conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(drop1, arch['conv3'][0], arch['conv3'][1], activation=tf.nn.relu)  # # TODO: add padding
    drop1_2 = tf.layers.dropout(conv3, arch['dropout1'], training=is_training)
    conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(drop1_2, arch['conv4'][0], arch['conv4'][1], activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv4, arch['pool2'][0], arch['pool2'][0])

    drop2 = tf.layers.dropout(pool2, arch['dropout2'], training=is_training)

    flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(drop2)

    fc1 = tf.layers.dense(flat, arch['N'])

    out = tf.layers.dense(fc1, n_classes)
    ### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ###

    return out
```

And the training function:

```
def train_test_model(hypers, save_final_model=False):
    # Running the training session
    print("Starting training session...")
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Run the initializer
        sess.run(init)
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples / hypers.batch_size)
        # Training cycle
        try:
            for epoch in range(hypers.n_epochs):
                avg_cost = 0.

                # Loop over all batches
                for i in range(total_batch):
                    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(hypers.batch_size)
                    # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                  y: batch_y})
                    # Compute average loss
                    avg_cost += c / total_batch
                # Display logs per epoch step
                if epoch % display_step == 0:

                    # Test model
                    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

                    # Calculate accuracy
                    # ORIGINAL:
                    # accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
                    # train_err = 1-accuracy.eval({x: mnist.train.images, y: mnist.train.labels})
                    # valid_err = 1-accuracy.eval({x: mnist.validation.images, y: mnist.validation.labels})

                    # WITH BATCHES FOR LESS MEM ALLOC
                    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))
                    train_acc = 0
                    for i in range(total_batch):
                        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(hypers.batch_size)
                        train_acc += accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch_x,
                                                              y:batch_y})
                    train_acc /= total_batch

                    train_err = 1 - train_acc
                    valid_err = 1 - accuracy.eval({x: mnist.validation.images, y: mnist.validation.labels})
                    # Display accuracy
                    print("Epoch:", '%05d' % (epoch + 1), ", cost=",
                          "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost), ", train_err=", "{:.4f}".format(train_err), ", valid_err=",
                          "{:.4f}".format(valid_err))

                if epoch % 5 == 0:
                    v = input('Do you want to stop the model? [Y/n]')
                    if 'y' in v.lower():
                        raise KeyboardInterrupt

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            hypers.n_epochs = epoch
            print("SIGINT Received, interrupting the training")



        print("\nOptimization Finished!\n")

        # Test model
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(test_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        # Calculate accuracy
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        # modified to batches
        train_acc = 0
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(hypers.batch_size)
            train_acc += accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                  y: batch_y})
        train_acc /= total_batch
        train_err = 1 - train_acc
        #
        valid_err = 1 - accuracy.eval({x: mnist.validation.images, y: mnist.validation.labels})
        print("Optimized for ", '%05d' % (epoch + 1), "epochs, to obtain training error", "{:.4f}".format(train_err),
              ", and validation error", "{:.4f}".format(valid_err))
        confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        print("\nValidation Confusion matrix:\n",
              confusion.eval({x: mnist.validation.images, y: mnist.validation.labels}))
```

Comment: Correct my if I'm wrong, but I can't see the calls to conv_net(). Can you provide a complete code snippet ? BTW you can give a is_training placeholder to the 'training' attribute of the tf.layers.dropout function. If you do this, you can then directly feed the is_training value in the feed dictionary wich removes the need to redefine the graph between train and test loops.

Comment: I could not spot anything obviously wrong. It would greatly help if you provide a complete small example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the full code, I'm sorry if there is some mess, i'm still learning
https://pastebin.com/M70LCt8j

BTW @OlivierDehaene thank you for the tip, didn't think about it.